# MySQL substring returns false when used in a WHERE clause and the result is '0'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a select of values in my table based on a binary code represented as varchar in one column, for example "values.todo" = 101, so I would make the following sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM values WHERE SUBSTRING(todo,2,1);
```

I understand that comparing the substring to something explicitly would be more precise and actually is how the query is done, but my question is why the given query considers the returned value of '0' at the position 2,1 as false and therefor does return 0 results?

Comment: You can use bit operators instead, for example if todo='101' `todo & 2` will return 0 while `todo & 4` will return 4 and `todo & 1` will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html), this should work:

> Comparison operations result in a value of 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE), or NULL. These operations work for both numbers and strings. Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary.

if you scroll down further you'll see examples of select statement where 0 is treated as false, ...